# what should I do with css top value differences in chrome and firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, css-position

The css top or margin-top values in chrome is so different with firefox and opera,what should I do? For example in chrome when I put (top:0px;) for (.slide_content) my menu is in its right place,but in firefox I have to put (top:-80px;).

What should I do?please help;Thanks in advance.

and also firebug doesn't have any errors. Sorry I couldn't post a jsfiddle link because the site contains lots of pictures and I really wanted to post pictures so that you can understand what I mean better,I tried but I needed 10 reputation but I have only 8,but this is my code:
 css:

```
    .tabbed_content {
        background-image:url('images/ct.png');
        width: 620px;
             height:62px;       
                 }

    .tabs {
        height: 62px;
        position: relative;
       /* top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 313px;*/
    }

    .tabs .moving_bg {
        background-color:#7F822A;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 125px;
        z-index: 190;
        left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 29px;
        background-position: left bottom;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                     top: 3px;
                     height: 15px;
                     padding-left: 15px;
                     padding-right: 15px;
                     padding-top: 15px;
                 }

    .tabs .tab_item {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 125px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 200;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;top:-130px;
    }

    .tabbed_content .slide_content {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-image: url('images/bkg.png');
        padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
        position: relative;
        top:0px;     /*THE PROBLEM IS HERE*/

    }
    .tabbed_content
    {
     width:310px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
     margin-left:15px;
    }
    .slide_content {width:940px;height:380px;}
    .tabslider {
        width: 5000px;
    }

    .tabslider div {
        float: left;
        width: 560px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-right: 40px;width:900px;
    }
 a.ma:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
     a.ma{text-decoration:none; color:White;margin-left:650px;}

      #menu
        {

 position:relative;

            z-index:1;
            bottom: -50px;
            left:-175px;
            width: 1016px;
        }

#menu ul {

            z-index:9999;

            width: 866px;
            margin-left: 150px;
        }
        #menu ul li{height:400px;float:left;list-style:none;z-index:9999;


        }
        #menu li a{display:block;height:63px;z-index:9999;

font-size:20px;padding-top:90px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;color:white;
            margin-left: 0px;
            }
            #menu li a:hover, #menu #menu_active a{}
.nav1 {background:url('images/menu1.gif')  center 35px  no-repeat    }
.nav2 {background:url('images/menu4.gif') center 35px no-repeat}
.nav3 {background:url('images/menu5.gif') center 35px no-repeat}
.nav4 {background:url('images/abus.gif') center 0px no-repeat}

.nav1:hover, .nav1#active {background:url('images/menu1_active.gif') center 31px no-repeat #001527}
.nav2:hover, .nav2#active {background:url('images/menu4_active.gif') center 31px no-repeat #001527}
.nav3:hover, .nav3#active {background:url('images/menu5_active.gif') center 31px no-repeat #001527}

.wrapper {overflow:hidden;float:right; height: 450px; margin-left: 63px;margin-right:0px; width: 941px;
position: relative; 
    z-index: 2;
            top: 0px;
            left: -32px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="background:url('images/toolbar2.png') no-repeat center top; height: 265px; width: 1013px;position:relative;">
    <div class="wrapper"> 
    <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Andalus" 
        Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="White" Text="Welcome To Saray Ceram"></asp:Label>


                            <br />

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


                                <div style="height: 26px;margin-top:-70px; ">
                                 <a class="ma"  href="#">Site Map</a>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                                        style="Width:149px;margin-right:2px; margin-left: 650px;"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <div style="width: 27px; height: 27px; background-image:url('images/s.png') ;position:relative; bottom:29px; left: 810px;" onclick="" ></div>    




                    </div>
    <div id="menu"  > 
   <ul>
                        <li class="nav1" style="margin-left:50px;height: 154px"><a href="#" style="width:201px">&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li> 

                        <li class="nav4" style="width:201px; height: 154px; margin-left: 0px;"><a href="#" style="width:200px"></a></li>

                        <li class="nav3" style="width:200px; height: 154px;margin-left: 0px;"><a href="#" style="width:200px">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li class="nav2" style="width:201px; height: 154px;margin-left: 0px;"><a href="#" style="width:200px">Products</a></li>      

                         </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>


    </div>
<div style=" background-image:url('images/bg_top2.jpg'); height: 600px; width: 990px; margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px"> 
    <br />
    <br />
        <div class='tabbed_content'> 
                    <div class='tabs'> 
                        <div class='moving_bg'> 
                            &nbsp;
                        </div> 
                        <span class='tab_item'> 
                            Wall Tale
                        </span> 
                        <span class='tab_item'> 
                            Floor Tale
                        </span> 

                    </div> 

                    <div class='slide_content'>                     
                        <div class='tabslider'> 
                            <div> 

                                               sth comes here
                            </div> 
                            <div  > 
                                                       and here
                            </div> 

                        </div> 

                    </div>

                    </div>

     <br /> 
     <br />

<div  style=" background-image:url('images/bg_bot.jpg');width:988px;height:105px;margin-top:400px;" >
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Andalus" 
        Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" Text="Copy Right © 2013 For Saray Ceram"></asp:Label>

    </div>
```

It also consists of some javascript functions but I think they have nothing to do with my problem.I will be really really thankful for your help,this has become a big problem for me.
also some one suggested me to use normalize.css I copy and pasted it to ma stylesheet and included it in my website,but nothing changed.

Comment: now you have more than 10 reputation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually Firefox and Chrome will/should render the same unless something is terribly wrong.

First run your rendered HTML through the [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and make sure there are no errors.

Then try getting rid of all those `&nbsp;`, and also try using a [CSS reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)

Comment: how should i use a css reset?just include it?

Comment: Yeah. All browsers usually have their own default values for elements which includes margins and whatnot, CSS reset will just set all of those values to be the same on all browsers. Simply add the YUI reset to your page and it should render more uniformly across browsers.

Do note that you might find a lot of wonky things happening once you add it in if you've started your site without it, but it's a much needed addition.

Answer (score 0):

Following things have to be keep in mind while working on browser compatibility:

1) Applying reset styles on all HTML elements. default styles for html elements are not same in all browsers.So first thing should be done is including reset styles. rest.css would have the styles as shown below:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

2) Understanding the CSS Box model properly. browser treats each element as a box and applies styles on top of it.

3) How to use float to arrange the individual sections in a html page.

4) How to use positioning elements?